# How can I search a textbox for word and replace it with word on textchanged?

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net, string, visual-studio-2010

When a user types into my textbox I would like for it to automatically correct a couple of words if they are entered without beginning with a capital letter. This is kind of like how visual studio corrects vb syntax. An example of this is:

The user types "else" and it automatically corrects it to say "Else". I know I would need it to do this on textchanged event. I am just not just not sure how to do it.

I am using vb.net.

Comment: I would handle the keydown event

Comment: Well I figure textchanged would be better since their is the possibility that text could be pasted into the textbox.

Comment: But you state types.  You really can't find how to handle the textchanged event on msdn.microsoft.com.  You don't list WPF or WinForms.  How is this regex?

Comment: I don't understand why you are mentioning msdn, I didn't know I had to state whether it was WPF or WinForms, and because I figure regex might be a good way to find the match for the word, thank you very much. What exactly is your issue? I wasn't trying to prove you wrong by saying textchanged is better suited. Thanks for the downvote.

Comment: Asking us to provide you the code is not for SO. Please post what you tried and what is the problem you are facing. A question as it is now will only garner downvotes. You say handling an event is better. Now did you try? What went wrong? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

if your question is relating to start caps then here is the code i am using in my project.

```
Public Sub StartCaps(ByRef mCtrl As Object)
    Dim mTypeName As String
    mTypeName = TypeName(mCtrl)
    Select Case mTypeName
        Case "TextBox"
            Dim sel_start As Integer, sel_length As Integer
            Dim txtProperCase As TextBox
            txtProperCase = CType(mCtrl, TextBox)
            sel_start = txtProperCase.SelectionStart
            sel_length = txtProperCase.SelectionLength
            txtProperCase.Text = StrConv(txtProperCase.Text, VbStrConv.ProperCase)
            txtProperCase.SelectionStart = sel_start
            txtProperCase.SelectionLength = sel_length
        Case "ComboBox"
            Dim sel_start As Integer, sel_length As Integer
            Dim cmbProperCase As ComboBox
            cmbProperCase = CType(mCtrl, ComboBox)
            sel_start = cmbProperCase.SelectionStart
            sel_length = cmbProperCase.SelectionLength
            cmbProperCase.Text = StrConv(cmbProperCase.Text, VbStrConv.ProperCase)
            cmbProperCase.SelectionStart = sel_start
            cmbProperCase.SelectionLength = sel_length
        Case "DataGridView"
            Dim grdProperCase As DataGridView, mCell As DataGridViewCell
            grdProperCase = CType(mCtrl, DataGridView)
            If Not grdProperCase Is Nothing Then
                mCell = grdProperCase.CurrentCell
                If Not mCell Is Nothing AndAlso Not mCell.Value Is Nothing Then
                    mCell.Value = StrConv(mCell.Value.ToString, VbStrConv.ProperCase)
                End If
            End If
    End Select
End Sub
```

Here is it calls from controls TextChanged event

```
Private Sub txtSname_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtSname.TextChanged, txtName.TextChanged
    StartCaps(sender)
End Sub
```

-------------- It may help you in your code ------ good luck ---